# Looking for a network monitor that can enumerate outbound connections

Tags: privacy, networking

I have a rooted Galaxy S2, and I want to block access for all apps whose primary function does not require network connectivity. I am using [DroidWall](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free) and [LBE Privacy Guard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite) (both require root) to control application behavior.

Droidwall is an excellent firewall, but it doesn't provide a snapshot of currently active network connections. Is there an app that can do so, on a per app basis?

**Update** : Just realized I can simplify things by just saying I want for Android what I can achieve using netstat -b on Windows, but properly presented!

I have already seen a few - but they just wrap a commandline interface - as though they're calling netstat locally and then just piping output.

Comment: I see a bunch of apps that come back on the Market with a search for "[netstat](https://market.android.com/search?q=netstat)". What have you already tried? Why didn't they work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opensource [Network Log](http://code.google.com/p/iptableslog/) ([Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.networklog)) app does exactly that. The features are:

- real time log display
- hostname resolving
- per app view
- filters based on app name, hostname, port

It needs root and busybox.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on a HTC One X now, but haven't rooted it yet.. Will give it a try.

Comment: There are other apps doing similar without root, e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.secuso.privacyfriendlynetmonitorapp