# Monitor Outbound Connections

Tags: networking, privacy

I just got a new LG G4, and connected it to my office wifi.
The network IT guy asked what I had running on my phone because it was making a lot of network connection calls.
He said he saw 3 in about a minute in his log, which was abnormal.

So I'm looking for something similar to this: [Looking for a network monitor that can enumerate outbound connections](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16743) , but without needing root.

I'm a little worried that it may be using mobile data without me knowing, and would like to stay on top of it.

Comment: Which Android version are you using? You can try [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor) to show active connections, and [NoRoot Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall) which will show notifications/logs based on app request to connections (run it in all blacklist mode, and allow each app one by one and notice which one is the cause of abnormal behavior; or try your own technique).

Comment: See related answers [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/86844/16575) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/43150/16575), also [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/43448/16575) – basically saying what @Firelord already wrote, but giving some more details: [OS Monitor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.eolwral.osmonitor) is your choice here.

Answer (score 0):

Most android devices now have monitors built within their software. I'm not familiar with the G4 so I can't say for certain it has the feature but my Samsung S5 does so I can lead you to it based off of that.

If you go to Settings there may be an item labeled "Data Usage". If not, look for "Mobile Data" and see if its in there. Within there it will show what apps are using data and how much data they're using. It's a great way to monitor your device.

Comment: I would like to know how your answer addresses *"He said he saw 3 in about a minute in his log, which was abnormal."*

Comment: I am looking for something a little more fine grained. The Data monitor shows large data usage, but not necessarily frequent small usage.