# Check system VPN statistics?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, networking, connection-issues, logging, vpn

Is there any way to check VPN stats for stock PPTP VPN applet? Maybe some stat-file or GUI-way? If not, can we utilize Tasker for that?

I particularly interested in *uptime* indicator, i.e. was my VPN disconnected during last 24h or not?

I saw [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16743/looking-for-a-network-monitor-that-can-enumerate-outbound-connections/) and [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.networklog), mentioned in the question, but it was last updated in 2015 and seems to be [not working on Marshmallow](https://github.com/pragma-/networklog/issues/18), which I am on (LG G3).

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Tasker, try setting up an appropriate task for the profile State → Net → VPN Connected. No clue if it works on Marshmallow though.

Comment: `an appropriate task` what kind of? How do I save the statistics?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Maybe you can keep an Entry as well as an Exit task for VPN connected, so if the VPN disconnects/re-connects the task writes the current time to a file since you are looking for uptime.